# Hook into meteor reset

Tags: meteor

Is it possible to hook into [`meteor reset`](http://docs.meteor.com/#meteorreset)? I want to delete all user uploads when this command is run.

Answer (score 1):

Keep in mind that the `meteor reset` would not be available in a deployed application, thought not 100% sure on this as it should be.

While you can't directly hook into it without modifying meteor.js the reset function is extremely simple and you could mimic it in a different way:

**Method 1**

All meteor reset does is remove all the files in `yourproject/.meteor/local` you could do that with a bash script, or make another node js file that does the same too:

The source of the meteor reset function (if you decide to make it in node):

```
var local_dir = path.join(app_dir, '.meteor', 'local');
files.rm_recursive(local_dir);
```

**Method 2**

This method would work in production mode. Seeing as meteor reset just clears the database you could just do it manually (while meteor is runnining too!):

Server js

```
Meteor.methods({
    resetme: function(password) {
        var require = meteor_bootstrap.require;
        var path = require('path');

        if(password=="1234") {
            Collection1.remove({});
            Collection2.remove({});
            Collection3.remove({});

            var local_dir = path.join(app_dir, 'yourfiledirectory');

            //recursively delete your files in local_dir
            return true;
         }
         else
         {
             return false;
         }
    }
});
```

Client (if you want)

```
Meteor.call("resetme", "1234", function(err,result) { if(err) { console.log("Error resetting"); } else { if(result) {console.log("Reset complete")}});
```

**Method 3** (more of a hook)

You could bundle your application and edit meteor.js to add the functionality you want. Updates will have the hook destroyed, however.